# What are the feature differences between Windows 7 Enterprise and Ultimate?

Tags: windows-7, windows, comparison, windows-edition

Are there any feature differences between Windows 7 Ultimate and Windows 7 Enterprise, or is the only difference licensing? Microsoft's [Compare editions](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/compare-editions/default.aspx) page doesn't list Enterprise, but their [Windows 7 Enterprise features](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/enterprise/products/windows-7/features.aspx) page seems to list the same features as Ultimate.

Comment: If you want to try out Enterprise, go here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/cc442495.aspx?ITPID=sprblog

Answer (score 16, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions
Looks like it *is* just a difference in licensing between Enterprise and Ultimate.

Interesting to note that Vista Ultimate and Enterprise did have some actual differences in functionality (namely, no Windows Media Center or Ultimate Extras in the Enterprise edition):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista_editions

UPDATE:
And [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprogeneral/thread/bbf8edc6-6380-4f84-af7d-9244b8f103e3) is a thread with several MS MVPs confirming that the only difference between Windows 7 Ultimate and Enterprise is the licensing model.

Comment: I'm guessing Microsoft decided to make Ultimate and Enterprise the same for 7 since Vista did not have a volume license key for Ultimate, and the Enterprise version was missing features only contained in Ultimate.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 Enterprise edition is designed to address the needs of our enterprise customers who have needs around advanced data protection, enabling user productivity and streamlining their PC management. Windows 7 Enterprise is part of the Windows Optimized Desktop offering, which also includes the Microsoft Desktop Optimization Pack (MDOP) tools and will only be available to customers with Microsoft Software Assurance on their Windows client licenses.

http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/business/archive/2009/02/11/windows-7-enterprise-edition-customer-benefits.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The features unique to Windows 7 Enterprise are:

- License rights to run up to four additional copies of Windows in virtual machines
- Ability to activate against a local key server.

Comment: Those features are not unique to Enterprise as Ultimate contains them as well.

Answer (score 0):

Paul Thurrott has two extensive articles on the different Windows 7 editions:

- [Windows 7 Product Editions: A Comparison](http://www.winsupersite.com/win7/win7_skus_compare.asp)
- [Windows 7 Product Editions Overview](http://www.winsupersite.com/win7/win7_skus.asp)

Answer (score 0):

They are the same you can't get Enterprise for normal people, its only for Crop. But for Ultimate anybody can get it. They have the exact function list. Just have different ways of licensing the product