# What are the differences between the different versions of windows 7:ultmate, home....?

Tags: windows-7, windows-edition

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What edition of Windows 7 should I purchase and install?](https://superuser.com/questions/91874/what-edition-of-windows-7-should-i-purchase-and-install)
>   [Windows 7: Ultimate vs Enterprise?](https://superuser.com/questions/20669/windows-7-ultimate-vs-enterprise)

Well I was just wondering what these names mean and what differences they make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/compare/default.aspx